# Excel-VBA Prompt user to input what column is to be searched?

Tags: excel, vba

first post :)

I have the following code below, which selects all within a set column and clears the two text phrases, from row 12 down.

What i want is to have the user input the column instead? possibly via InputBox?

---

```
Sub ClearColumn()
  Dim lastCell As Long

    Dim myRange As Range

'   Find lastCell in column Z
    lastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

'   Set range to look at
    Set myRange = Range("Z12:Z" & lastCell)

'   Replace All Pass
    myRange.Replace What:="Go", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'   Replace All Fail
    myRange.Replace What:="Stop", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Well, why didn't you try a `InputBox` then? I'm sure you will find information about how to use a input box. Give it a try, if it fails come back [edit] the question and show the code you have tried • Note that just because you put a question mark behind a sentence it doesn't get a question automatically: --> *"Prompt user to input what column is to be searched?"*

Comment: Look at `offset` so `Range("A12:A" & lastCell).offset(0,COLUMN_NUMBER)`  Or even, look closely at what you are doing `Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").`  obviously takes numeric values, so instead of the Z here ....

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange. You seem to have answered your own question. Below code is untested, but should take a small amount of time to implement.

```
Sub ClearColumn()
  Dim lastCell As Long
  Dim chooseColumn As Variant
  Dim myRange As Range

  chooseColumn = InputBox("Which Column do you want to alter?")

'   Find lastCell in column Z
    lastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, chooseColumn ).End(xlUp).Row

'   Set range to look at
    Set myRange = Range(chooseColumn &"12:"&chooseColumn & lastCell)

'   Replace All Pass
    myRange.Replace What:="Go", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'   Replace All Fail
    myRange.Replace What:="Stop", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


End Sub
```

Let us know how you go :)

Comment: Note, this will accept text entries only, it will fail if the user enters say column 3, so you may wish to trap that also.

Comment: Brilliant thats worked :) was so close! - appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as answered if its done and dusted :)